# how to replace alias_method_chain in activerecord-sqlserver-adapter gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to connect a secondary server( Microsoft SQL Server) to pull info from specifically for one form I have in my rails app. I use sqlite3 for my other forms. Is there a way to solve this issue? The issue is with the gem itself as the alias_method_chain is deprecated. Are there any gems alternatives I can implement, or a way to rewrite the gem file itself? here is the piece of code it is throwing errors for:

```
module ActiveRecord

        def self.included(klass)
          klass.extend ClassMethods
          class << klass
            alias_method_chain :reset_column_information, :sqlserver_cache_support
            alias_method_chain :add_order!, :sqlserver_unique_checking
            alias_method_chain :add_limit!, :sqlserver_order_checking

          end
        end
```

. I tried to use the prepend method with no luck. Thank you

Comment: I've got this issue too. How did you go? Any tips?